# Why does fgets fail when I use 0 as FILE* to read from stdin in rop chain?

Tags: buffer-overflow, stack-overflow

I am making a rop chain to call fgets with stdin as input to be able to make a basic stackoverflow.

But my issue is that when I call fgets with 0 as third argument (for stdin) fgets crash at

```
 <fgets+49>       mov    ecx, DWORD PTR [esi]
```

where esi is the third argument I control, why does it crash ? With 0 it should not try to read the content of it and just read from stdin, no ?

The useful part of my ropchain looks like :

```
fgets.plt
pop_pop_pop_ret
buffer
0x500
0
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work
the call made is something like :

```
_IO_fgets(buf=0xf7f77000, n=0x500, fp=0x0)
```

Thanks

Comment: This question belongs to StackOverflow not Security StackExchange.

Comment: The third argument expected by fgets is a pointer to a `FILE` structure, not an integer file descriptor.

Comment: because 0 isn't a valid FILE* ? What happens when you call `fgets(buffer, 0x500, NULL)` in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing [stdio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output) files ([`FILE*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io), a high-level interface to files) and [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (a number). `fgets` is an stdio function and takes a `FILE*` as an argument. Standard input is file descriptor 0, but `stdin` in the stdio interface. Likewise standard output is 1 and `stdout`, and standard error is 2 and `stderr`.

Passing 0 (or any small integer) where `fgets` expects a `FILE*` causes the program to attempt to dereference this value as an address, which fails (for 0, which is a null pointer, it fails with a segmentation fault; depending on the architecture, values that aren't a multiple of the word size may fail with a bus error or an illegal instruction).

Comment: Thank you, you're right , sorry for my dumb question then !